# How do i optimise my python code which reads Battery Staus

Tags: python, batterylevel

Basically i was trying to make a Py script what runs in background to notify the user when to plug in the charger and when to disconnect

the problem which i am facing is with the performance,The script uses more CPU time(May be because i used while loop)

Tell me if there is any better method to handle such a scenario.

I have already tried using sleep time but that did not work.

```py
class Battery_code:

    def __init__(self, c_var):
        self.c_var = c_var

    def mbox(self, title, text, style):
        return Custom.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)



    while 1:
        battery = Reader.sensors_battery()
        plugged = battery.power_plugged
        percent = str(battery.percent)
        if plugged is False and int(percent) in range(40, 80, 1) and c_var == 0:
            speak.Speak("Charger is Disconnected Now")
            c_var += 1
            time.sleep(2)
        if plugged is True and int(percent) in range(40, 80, 1) and c_var == 0:
            speak.Speak("Charger is Connected Now")
            c_var += 1
            time.sleep(2)
        if plugged is True and int(percent) > 80:
            mbox('',
                 'Battery is at [' + percent + '%] and Still Plugged Please Unplug ', 0)
            speak.Speak("Please Unplug the charger to increase battery life")
            c_var = 0
        if plugged is False and int(percent) < 40:
            mbox('',
                 'Battery is at [' + percent + '%] Please Connect Charger  ', 0)
            speak.Speak("Please Connect charger to increase battery life")
            c_var = 0
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: "uses more CPU time" - more than what rate and what's the expected performance?

Comment: Please, use more time sleep in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the support the issue is solved now, I didn't use more sleep time in If conditions so the program was getting executed repeatedly and cpu useage was more than 16% but now it has reduced to 2-4% and is constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "battery.secsleft" to figure out how much time the user has left.

Then with some simple math you can figure out when to give the alert and sleep until then.
Of course, this can vary by usage, so you can use some extra padding for the time.

Also, in cases:
if plugged is True and int(percent) > 80:
and
if plugged is False and int(percent) < 40:

you forgot to use sleep.